# ggplot error: Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y, : polygon edge not found

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was running someone's code from GitHub, and it produced an error:

> Error in grid.Call(C_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,
>   : polygon edge not found

can someone help me to understand where it went wrong?

The code is this:

```
ggplot() +

  # municipality polygons
  geom_polygon(data = map_data, 
               aes(fill = avg_age_15, x = long, y = lat, group = group)) +

  # municipality outline
  geom_path(data = map_data, 
            aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), 
            color = "white", size = 0.1) +

  coord_equal() +

  # add the previously defined basic theme
  theme_map() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL, 
       title = "Switzerland's regional demographics", 
       subtitle = "Average age in Swiss municipalities, 2015", 
       caption = "Geometries: ThemaKart, BFS; Data: BFS, 2016")
```

Comment: Can you please encapsulate all the data necessary to reproduce this problem in your question?

Comment: I just found it here, all of data and codes were from this link: https://github.com/grssnbchr/thematic-maps-ggplot2

Comment: Please include all the necessary parts within your question. Avoid linking to offsite resources.